# Disable Windows Visual Effects through SystemParametersInfo

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pinvoke

I am trying to disable all visual effects programmatically in a Windows Forms App. Other than an extense list of registry values to be changed, i found this option, but I cant seem to get it to work.

Searched in pinvoke.net and on MSDN for a more specific answer, but I could not find one.

So, heres the data I have:

Info about SPI_SETUIEFFECTS

> SPI_SETUIEFFECTS
>   0x103F
>
> Enables or disables UI effects. Set the pvParam parameter to TRUE to enable all UI effects or FALSE to disable all UI effects.

I need to pass it a bool as the pvParam, which seems to be an exception to the general rule... ok, then I try declaring it as:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, bool pvParam, uint fWinIni);
```

now, to call it:

```
const uint SPI_SETUIEFFECTS = 0x103F;
const uint SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;

bool result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETUIEFFECTS, 0, false, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

And it builds, runs... and does nothing. No error, no change. "result" is set to true.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you try with pvParam as `ref bool pvParam`, it's supposed to be a pointer

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the reply. I figured that since it doesnt need to modify the bool I might as well pass it directly instead of referenced. Still, I tried declaring `ref bool pvParam`, assigning `bool f = false`, and then passing `ref f`. I get the same result.

Comment: Have you tried SPIF_SENDCHANGE + SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE (and the ref bool again)

Comment: @Simon If you mean `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETUIEFFECTS, 0, ref t, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE|SPIF_SENDCHANGE);` I was just trying that right now. Nothing.

Comment: @SimonMourier It's not supposed to be a pointer for `SPI_SETUIEFFECTS`. The documentation makes that clear, for that particular action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
    uint uiAction, 
    uint uiParam, 
    bool pvParam, 
    uint fWinIni
);
....
bool enabled = false;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETUIEFFECTS, 0, enabled, 0);
```

works perfectly. I tested by looking at the drop-down effect of a combo box. When `enabled` is `false` then the combo's list appears instantly. When `enabled` is `true` then the combo's list slides down.

Most likely you are looking at a control which is not painted by the system and that control is ignoring this option.

Comment: Well, this is embarrasing. You are right, the code did work, I was just not looking at the right place. Thx for the reply.