# Disable windows effect

Tags: c#, windows, system

I'm intrested in disabling the classic windows effect-such as the fade in effect when you open a window.. etc.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564925/disable-windows-visual-effects-through-systemparametersinfo), i've tried to call the `SystemParametersInfo` in order to disable the effect,tried the suggestion in the solution.. but still.. i dont see any change...

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
        uint uiAction,
        uint uiParam,
        bool pvParam,
        uint fWinIni
    );


    public const uint SPI_SETANIMATION = 0x73;
    private  unsafe void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      bool enabled = false;
      SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETANIMATION, 0, enabled, 0);
    }
```

I'm using windows 10.
I'll appreciate any incoming help.Thanks!

Comment: What does it return (success/error)? And have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237231/disable-visual-effects-call-to-systemparamtersinfo-shows-no-effect

Comment: SPI_SETANIMATION would be the next guess.  Programs should not be doing this, leave user preferences up to the user.

Comment: @Lucero it returns 'true' for some reason.. but i still cannot see any change.. :(

Comment: @HansPassant like this?(look at the original question.edited). it still seems to not work..

Comment: It just isn't very clear to me what specific effect you are talking about.  My Windows 10 does not 'fade' anything.  Use Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced tab > Performance Settings button and tell us what specific checkbox has the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @HansPassant it's in hebrew so im not sure how to translate it good but leave it for now- im getting a "False" result for what youv'e suggested and also for other parameters now.. i dont know why is this ...

Comment: @HansPassant allright this is (in translation of course) the name of what im looking for :animate windows on resize/scale. got any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14002805/17034

Comment: @HansPassant no no no wer'e on the right truck.. just need to find the correct animation. thought it was this http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/microsoft/win32/NativeMethods.cs,34b7f513190a0b6f